# validation to prevent user entering a string or empty string in a do while loop

Tags: java, loops

This is probably something simple but i'm completely stumped. I need help preventing the user from entering a string or empty string in a do-while loop.

Code below

```
 do {

    int menuItem = input.nextInt();

    switch (menuItem) {

    case 1: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [1] - Add a employee to collection ------ ");     functions.addEmployee(); break;

    case 2: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [2] - Edit an employee  details ------  ");  functions.editEmployee(); break;

    case 3: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [3] - Delete an employee from collection ------  "); functions.deleteEmployee(); break;

    case 4: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [8] - Search employee  by keyword ------  "); functions.EmpSearchByKeyword(); break;

    default:    System.out.println("Please enter in a valid integer to operate menu system (1-4)");

        }               

    } while (input.hasNextInt());
```

Comment: Instead of using `do-while` loop, use `while`. What if a user enters his first String as `empty`, Then the do-while loop will fail you.You can use `if` condition to check whether the entered String is empty or not.

Comment: Just to clear things up, im using a while statement to check that an integer has been inputted ,then inside the while using an if statement to check if a user has entered a string?

Comment: No, Wrong Approach. Check the answers below to get an idea of what I am saying

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `while` loop not `do-while` like this:

```
     while (input.hasNextInt()){
     ....//your code
      }
```

Comment: ok so i have incorporated the while loop just as you said above, now if i enter a string it doesn't crash or get the mismatch error, is there a way i can get the loop to work again so that i can enter input in to use my switch statement as before?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
do {
while(true){
   try{
       int menuItem = input.nextInt();
       break;
   }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Error");
   }
}
switch (menuItem) {
   case 1: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [1] - Add a employee to collection ------ ");     functions.addEmployee(); break;

   case 2: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [2] - Edit an employee  details ------  ");  functions.editEmployee(); break;

   case 3: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [3] - Delete an employee from collection ------  "); functions.deleteEmployee(); break;

   case 4: System.out.println("------ You have selected choice [8] - Search employee  by keyword ------  "); functions.EmpSearchByKeyword(); break;

   default:    System.out.println("Please enter in a valid integer to operate menu system (1-4)");
   }               

} while (input.hasNextInt());
```